# Gzeira Shava by Purim II

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

We know that the Gemara (maseches smachos probably) darshens hilchos Yom Kippur from Purim

> כתיב הכא אך בעשור לחדש השביעי הזה יום הכפרים הוא וכתיב התם על כן קראו לימים האלה פורים מה להלן במשתה ושמחה אף כאן במשתה ושמחה

If so why dont we have an obligation to get drunk on Yom kippur also?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3):

We may drink on Yom Kippur, but this is normally limited to the *ish iti* ([*Vayikra* 16:21](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0316.htm#21)), reminiscent of the *chachamim yod'ei haitim* mentioned in *Esther* ([1:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3301.htm#13)). The Rambam mentions that, on the way out to the desert, the *ish iti* would be offered food and drink at each and every stop ([*Hil. Avodas Yom HaKippurim* 3:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=9053)). One would think that is enough to get intoxicated.

This *halacha* to feast and drink on Yom Kippur was also fulfilled by the masses in the generation of Sh'lomo HaMelech ([*Mo'ed Kattan* 9a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=12&daf=9&format=text)).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that it is forbidden to wear leather shoes on Yom Kippur so in the days before they had decent sneakers to wear instead, they used to walk around barefoot through the streets.

Chazal were worried that if the people were drunk they wouldn't be able to feel the hard ground beneath their feet properly and so decided it was better not.

Answer (score 2):

Some Rishoim answer that that since this wouldn't be in the spirit of Yom Kippur we fulfill the obligation through intoxication on *erev Yom Kippur*. (This is consistent with Rabbeinu Yonah's explanation of the feast on the eve of Yom Kippur.)

Answer (score 1):

I read that the  שֵׁכָר of Purim was satisfied by focusing on the שָׂכָר which results from proper teshuva.